# Tautochrone and Brachistochrone problems are equivalent

Tags: physics, mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations

It is a well known fact that the brachistochrone (the problem of finding the curve of quickest descent in a uniform gravitational field) and the tautochrone (the problem of finding a curve from which a particle with any starting point reaches the end in fixed point) have the same solution, the cycloid. Has anyone managed to show that a solution to one of these problems would solve the other *without* explicitly solving the problems?

Comment: Related?: [Is there an intuitive reason the brachistochrone and the tautochrone are the same curve?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/16819/is-there-an-intuitive-reason-the-brachistochrone-and-the-tautochrone-are-the-sam) [When is a brachistochrone not a tautochrone?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2853231/when-is-a-brachistochrone-not-a-tautochrone?rq=1)